# AWS EMR Spark save to S3 is very slow

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I have a Spark job running on EMR that takes unusually long time. Spark tasks themselves are running fast. When I save the result to S3 it spends more than 20mins doing this...

```
16/02/05 01:44:44 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 561CA7CD8C009E79), S3 Extended Request ID: B3dMnYkxE/QSZsD1VREBf5FR+uH8m5k2Tb8zZ+Y0+VFgQFSwRJjPEWV7wX61+9ZiJhY5nf35Rx8=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[561CA7CD8C009E79], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[12.766], HttpRequestTime=[12.494], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[11.067], RequestSigningTime=[0.103], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.071],
16/02/05 01:44:44 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[F84316D0C1958276], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[16.001], HttpRequestTime=[13.1], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[11.69], RequestSigningTime=[0.085], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001], ResponseProcessingTime=[2.673], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.071],
16/02/05 01:44:44 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: rename s3://my-bucket-name/stati/data/output/bidder4/_temporary/0/task_201602050130_0014_m_000001/organization_id=100932/impression_date=2016-01-01/part-r-00001-0e84d8cb-4b43-4cc3-b95e-65b1b9c12f25.gz.parquet s3://my-bucket-name/stati/data/output/bidder4/organization_id=100932/impression_date=2016-01-01/part-r-00001-0e84d8cb-4b43-4cc3-b95e-65b1b9c12f25.gz.parquet
16/02/05 01:44:44 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 014934F9C27E2969), S3 Extended Request ID: B313czEVYZR21sBpxHODqS4gCRudU249Jd5+Z+D0a4FGlHW6eQx0/GRNtTkrS2y4ucKND8DYWyg=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[014934F9C27E2969], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[11.854], HttpRequestTime=[11.598], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[10.168], RequestSigningTime=[0.098], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.078],
16/02/05 01:44:44 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 97FD09BE9E109D68), S3 Extended Request ID: oGOPBseyZF9/7OCtzwyOK+lCfALplBW+IOAFXIybKSHDtvMUyZeFFOGi7+qba6fo0ReV1sl9fl4=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[97FD09BE9E109D68], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[13.141], HttpRequestTime=[12.864], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[11.462], RequestSigningTime=[0.098], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.057],
16/02/05 01:51:13 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[7936D2099DD2EB95], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[8.471], HttpRequestTime=[8.209], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[6.947], RequestSigningTime=[0.09], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.08], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.042],
16/02/05 01:51:13 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: listStatus s3://my-bucket-name/stati/data/output/bidder4/_temporary/0/task_201602050130_0014_m_000004/organization_id=101041 with recursive false
16/02/05 01:51:13 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 4D2BAED335E4DD56), S3 Extended Request ID: NgmiU8R7X94wUHnYXhTB4aW0AIpQ9F1RHbmAwsFsh/x8D1/B7EFjAWgo8Z/Eluj18PKlVM7w2zQ=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[4D2BAED335E4DD56], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[22.181], HttpRequestTime=[22.004], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[20.697], RequestSigningTime=[0.053], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.052],
16/02/05 01:51:13 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[C554088E2B24A1F0], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[35.69], HttpRequestTime=[34.067], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[32.718], RequestSigningTime=[0.07], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], ResponseProcessingTime=[1.447], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.043],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 3ADAE326D46195E2), S3 Extended Request ID: peAwu6EY5NGjDMSHQQmhvYzqmvhjogefngu2BNaSh4a5O4QgUbYUM+TBlIZ2763PgiZOt2BtAqc=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[3ADAE326D46195E2], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[24.088], HttpRequestTime=[23.851], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[22.466], RequestSigningTime=[0.088], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.064],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: 069544819617C5F4), S3 Extended Request ID: gomSLQka0EMLiv+uo5zSjrXDhjxQBmvJMqyBJMiqozuEjppIup20RT/DqJZqrQPggDE0Dpzcr5Q=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[069544819617C5F4], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[51.626], HttpRequestTime=[51.351], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[49.956], RequestSigningTime=[0.081], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.05],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[E59C345260724310], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[14.771], HttpRequestTime=[13.035], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[11.65], RequestSigningTime=[0.092], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], ResponseProcessingTime=[1.533], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.072],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: listStatus s3://my-bucket-name/stati/data/output/bidder4/_temporary/0/task_201602050130_0014_m_000004/organization_id=101041/impression_date=2016-01-01 with recursive false
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: E1F7FDB93AB37E2F), S3 Extended Request ID: Tglj240gJvYWm2bvi0MSk4aaH4c5KWk/8l6UJIw/WS/wxRKPEed3mFUaX7PZWgVl8ESEF8TtCz8=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[E1F7FDB93AB37E2F], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[9.351], HttpRequestTime=[9.166], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[7.869], RequestSigningTime=[0.071], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.04],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[2228F32BADB3EAC6], ServiceEndpoint=[https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, ClientExecuteTime=[21.51], HttpRequestTime=[19.992], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[18.687], RequestSigningTime=[0.047], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.0], ResponseProcessingTime=[1.387], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.057],
16/02/05 01:51:14 INFO latency: StatusCode=[404], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: DAAFA5B4B81AAB0C), S3 Extended Request ID: 5BGDszg4CRVs0kN8S1hwdvpFknwqQZyGs+QOk0m6+U7K8HJ3eUpDEeYXMv6zt+Dx1cqknGDV+/U=], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[404 Not Found], AWSRequestID=[DAAFA5B4
```

I thought this is similar to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342214/spark-1-4-1-saveastextfile-to-s3-is-very-slow-on-emr-4-0-0) SO question.
I've set this in my config.json file as suggested there

```
{
  "Classification": "mapred-site",
  "Properties": {
    "mapred.output.direct.EmrFileSystem": "true",
    "mapred.output.direct.NativeS3FileSystem": "true"
  }
},
```

Still seeing the same behavior. EMR 4.3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the results are being uploaded twice with S3. Take a look [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/docs/sql-programming-guide.md)

Set the Hadoop property: `spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class` to `org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter`.

> Note the info regarding impact on speculative execution.

Comment: which version of spark you are using here ? can you please suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 2):

**pyspark**

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committ‌​er.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter")
```

**scala**

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committ‌​er.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter")
```

where sc is the SparkContext

Comment: which version of spark you are using here ? can you please suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the rest of your configuration.json? Something else appears to be wrong. Also on emr-4.3.0 the two settings you have given are not required. Or if you can post a cluster id I can help.

Comment: All configurations loaded by the cluster

    `mapred-site mapred.output.direct.NativeS3FileSystem true`
    
    `mapred-site mapred.output.direct.EmrFileSystem true`
    
    `spark maximizeResourceAllocation true`
    
    `spark-defaults spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 2560`
    
    `spark-defaults spark.executor.cores 12`
    
    `spark-defaults spark.executor.memory 24576`
    
    `yarn-site yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb 27172`
    
    `yarn-site yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb 27172`


    `yarn-site yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores 12`

Comment: I'm sorry formatting on above comment is not great. SO  seems to ignore new line. I can get the cluster ID if its needed.
BTW, I saw this when running code in Spark-Shell. Not sure if that makes a difference.